# Text as Variables with different elements In R

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm a beginner, I'm trying to make a data chart in r. So I have the obesity and GNIPerCapita as my x and y. Both of them are classified as Low income, High income, Lower Mid, Upper High Income, etc., How could I color them to indicate their group The data

[image]

Comment: Can you please make a reproducible example for us? Just do `dput(yourDataframe[1:20,])`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

So, is the `tidyverse`/ `ggplot` version of a coloured scatter plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
    mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = c(4,6,8))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(disp, hp, colour = cyl)) +
    geom_point()
```

[image]